# Collections to insert record at zero position

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

Which collection is better to insert records at first position. I know `LinkedList` is better, but it takes more memory than `list`. I have grid in which I have to insert around 200,000+ records in descending order. It's real time grid in which trades is being inserted. FYI. I am using `DevExpress` grid and my application is in `WPF`.

Comment: Why dont you do something like ``new List<T>(otherList.OrderByDescending())``, instead of trying to add every item individualy at first position?

Comment: I think creating new List on addition of each item addition will be slow.

Comment: Sorry but I dont fully understand your sentence? - But, from what I understood - why would you make both a new List and add items to it? I tried to show you a way thats remove the necessity of adding items to the list, by initializising the whole list at once which is faster than adding them one by one? - Thats why I used the constructor to pass a list into it with an ``.OrderByDescending()`` since you said you would like to have it in `descending order`. - since you didnt specify where you are getting your 200.000+ records, I made the simple solution of saying `otherList.OrderByDescending()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question but it seems as if you would like a data structure that you can iterate in LIFO (last in first out) order.

Assuming this is the case a stack data structure has LIFO behavior.

```
public class Model
{
    readonly Stack<object> _stack = new Stack<object>();

    public void InsertRecord(object record)
    {
        _stack.Push(record);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> Enumerate()
    {
        return _stack.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```